# Better way to count uncompleted reminders & update table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, eventkit

I'm using this to count all the uncompleted reminders in the defult list and put it in the detail of the table view cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
...
    NSPredicate *predicate2 = [self.reminderStore predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting:nil ending:nil calendars:@[[self.reminderStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders]]];
    [self.reminderStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate2 completion:^(NSArray *reminders)
    {
         cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [reminders count]];
         NSLog(@"count: %d", [reminders count]);
     }];
...
return cell;
}
```

The problem is that because it's on another thread, it's not updating the table cell until it needs to reload it. (it does prints in the log). What's the best way of fixing that, so it would load automatically and won't need to load again every time? Also, is there another way to faster count reminders?

Comment: A UITableView, resets the data in the cells when the tableview dequeue/resuses the cell, in order to not make it load, you would have to make another property for an array and store all the cells that you allocate in it, and then with in the cellforrow take the cells from that array and not reallocate them.

Comment: wouldn't the incomplete reminders be the same number as you returned in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: @A'saDickens how can I wait until the fetch completed? Also the table is not of reminders, it's table with this special cell.